# What port is a given program using?

Tags: windows, networking

I want to be able to figure out what port a particular program is using.  Are there any programs available online or that come with windows that will tell me which processes are using which ports on my computer?

PS - before you downmod this for not being a programming question, I'm looking for the program to test some networking code.

Comment: Regardless of whether you're going to use this as part of some programming project, it's not a programming problem.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

`netstat -b -a` lists the ports in use and gives you the executable that's using each one. I believe you need to be in the administrator group to do this, and I don't know what security implications there are on Vista.

I usually add `-n` as well to make it a little faster, but adding `-b` can make it quite slow.

*Edit*: If you need more functionality than netstat provides, [vasac suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105418/what-port-is-a-given-program-using#105487) that you try [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx).

Comment: If anybody has the rights to edit an answer, consider adding vasac's answer below (TCPView) for anybody that needs a more feature-full version of this with a real gui

Comment: I added the link to TCPView to my answer.

Comment: is there any way with firewall?

Comment: `-p` & `-b` options are unreliable, see my answer: https://superuser.com/questions/191416/pid-number-in-task-manager-cant-be-found/1639302#1639302

Answer (score 44):

[TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) can do what you asked for.

Comment: Thank you; netstat is more than enough for my needs but if I ever need something more hardcore I'll be sure to use TCPView.  Should be added to the accepted answer but alas I don't have the right to Edit yet.

Comment: I've been using the Netstat utility that comes with XAMPP. But this standalone utility is much useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

On Vista, you do need elevated privileges to use the -b option with netstat.  To get around that, you could run "netstat -ano" which will show all open ports along with the associated process id.  You could then use tasklist to lookup which process has the corresponding id.

```
C:\>netstat -ano

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  ...
  TCP    [::]:49335             [::]:0                 LISTENING       1056
  ...

C:\>tasklist /fi "pid eq 1056"

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
sqlservr.exe                  1056 Services                   0     66,192 K
```

Answer (score 13):

You may already have Process Explorer (from Sysinternals, now part of Microsoft) installed.  If not, go ahead and install it now -- it's just that cool.

In Process Explorer: locate the process in question, right-click and select the TCP/IP tab.  It will even show you, for each socket, a stack trace representing the code that opened that socket.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without selecting a process? In case one wants to locate a process by port?

Answer (score 7):

If your prefer a GUI interface [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) is free and works with all versions of windows. Shows ports and what process has them open.

Comment: another good alternative.  wow, didn't know this was such a popular subject :)

Answer (score 5):

"netstat -natp" is what I always use.

Answer (score 4):

Windows 8 (and likely 7 + Vista) also provide a view in Resource Monitor. If you select the Network tab, there's a section called 'Listening Ports'. Can sort by port number, and see which process is using it.

Comment: exactly what I needed, 10x!

Answer (score 3):

Windows comes with the `netstat` utility, which should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

At a command line, netstat -a will give you lots o' info.

Comment: I'd vote this up if I had any votes left.

Comment: -1: -a doesn't give process ID

Comment: @CharlesB It does if you add the `-o` option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'netstat' command for this.  There's a description of doing this sort of thing [here](http://www.petri.co.il/quickly_find_local_open_ports.htm).

Answer (score 0):

[Open Ports Scanner](http://www.download.com/Open-Ports-Scanner/3000-2085_4-10725872.html) works for me.

Answer (score -1):

most decent firewall programs should allow you to access this information. I know that Agnitum OutpostPro Firewall does.