# How to determine the software used by the port 80 in windows?

Tags: networking, port, wamp

How to find the software used by the port 80 in windows?

Comment: Do you want to know what is using port 80 on your machine, or what is using port 80 on a remote machine?

Comment: I want to know which s/w is installed in port 80 in my system

Comment: There is no such thing as 's/w installed in port 80 in your system'. There is just software that *uses* port 80 *when you run it.*

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something as simple as knowing if a program is using a particular port on your computer, you can use the command `netstat -b -a` on Windows. If netstat is not enough, use [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx)

You may need some network analysis tools. It is fairly common to use a tool (or combination of tools) that perform [port scanning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_scanner) as well as [packet sniffing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer). By analyzing the packets, you can determine what is being communicated.

**EDIT:** Possible duplicates:

- [How can you find out which process is listening on a port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48198/938695)
- [What port is a given program using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105418/what-port-is-a-given-program-using)

Comment: I need the port number along with the services name.How can i get it?