# How can I determine which port a network connection is using?

Tags: c++, winapi, networking

How can Windows be queried to determine which port each connection is using in C++?

Comment: "each connection"? You mean each program?

Comment: Is `netstat -a` gives the required info?

Comment: @AustinHenley: a single program can have multiple connections. So it is perfectly valid to query individual connections. If needed, it is possible to determine which program owns a given connection.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Right. But I didn't know if he was trying to find out all connections for every running program or just one particular program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What port is a given program using?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105418/what-port-is-a-given-program-using)

Comment: The suggested duplicate is answered using the command-line utility netstat; note that the question is about querying this with C++/WinAPI

Comment: Whoever downvoted the question, please leave a comment explaining why you did so.  Phantom downvotes are uninformative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried getting the TCP table?

You can ask windows for a table of all TCP connections which shows you the local address, the local port, the remote address, the remote port, and the process ID of the program that has that connection.

Getting The Table:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408406(v=vs.85).aspx

Table Entry:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb485761(v=vs.85).aspx

I won't try to make an example because there's a nice one at the first link. There's the equivalent for UDP as well should you need both types of connections.

Answer (score 2):

You can query what port a socket is bound to by using the [getsockname() API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then checking the sin_port field of the sockaddr_in structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `netstat -b -a` on Windows. If you must, this could be called as a `SHELL` call.