# WAMP is not starting completely

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver

I have latest version of wamp i.e WAMPSERVER (64 bit & PHP 5.5) 2.5 installed. It's not starting completely, not turning to green and so MySQL is not starting even though the port is used by Apache itself.

I have also installed Visual Studio 2012 VC 11 vcredist_x64/86.exe for my Windows 8.1 64bit OS.

Very weird, all the paths are configured in paths and also extensions enabled.

[image]

Below image specifies the sufficient ports in use:

[image]

@RiggsFolly - Thanks for the neat explanation. As per your questionnaires, I wanted to confirm that I have just installed 64 bit Wamp version and not 32bit. But installed Visual Studio 2012 VC 11 vcredist_x64 and x86 thinking.

**FYI:** As I had stated earlier in my question I have installed MySQL_Workbench in my system. But i have disabled its services to run on startup. May I know is that causing problem?

Please find the image of errors as per the [MySQL Errors logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iac6q.png)

And please find [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1xrW.png) for windows application MySQL error logs

**My last question is:** can't we have both MySQL_Workbench & Wamp together?

Comment: It looks like there is already an Apache server running on your machine. Also, please add more info, like config files and such..

Comment: AFAIK this question doesn't belong to StackOverflow since it's for programming questions only. It should belong to ServerFault. Please consider deleting this question here and open it on ServerFault.

Comment: As pointed out by @nana, the obvious reason seems to be an already running server on your machine. But if you need more help, please consider asking it on ServerFault as suggested by Paulo.

Comment: @nana, what config files you require. I have mysql workbench installed as well in my machine, but i have disabled that as an service in startup for now. Is that causing any problem. And that occupied message or port is returned when it turns to orange. Before starting of wamp, it will be empty. Hope you are clear. I guess mysql workbench is not disturbing anything as i have manually disabled it.

Comment: Other program is using port 80...maybe skype? It uses port 80 by default...

Comment: I am not on windows so I won't be able to help, sorry. PauloMiguelAlmeida and Abhay are right, you should really ask this on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Use this to know what program is listening there... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105418/what-port-is-a-given-program-using

Comment: I agree with @PauloMiguelAlmeida. I am ready to move. Can any of yourself move this question to serverfault as i don't have reputation in it to post images please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first image, I assume is the result of running

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Test port 80
```

This tests the port that Apache should be using i.e. port 80. It should report

```
Your port 80 is not actually used.
```

But only if you have not started Apache!!! If you have started the Apache service in WAMPServer, it will of course report that port 80 is being used by Apache 2.4.9 etc etc...

> This looks like what you have done! So its not a problem.

*One thing though* You say you installed WAMPServer 64bit, but the image reports that Apache 32bit is running **??? What do you really have installed ???** Or do you have both 32bit and 64bit WAMPServer installed?

> If you have installed both 32bit and 64bit I suggest that you pick one or the other. I suggest the 32bit WAMPServer as the 64bit PHP is still not a complete port and considered *Experimental* until PHP7.

Now you appear to be saying already that the reason the wampmanager icon is not green is that MySQL has not started, so all the above is irrelevant. **MYSQL runs on port 3306** and not 80, only one program can use a port, they cannot share ports.

So to see why MySQL has not started, look at the MySQL error log.

```
wampmanager -> MYSQL -> Error log
```

If that is empty, as it is sometimes if the error is so serious that MYSQL has not had time to open its log file before the error causes it to terminate, look at the Windows Event Log

To launch Windows Event Viewer do :

> Windows Key + R to launch the run dialog
>
> then enter **eventvwr.exe** and press the OK button
>
> On the left side of the windows click 'Windows Logs -> Applications'
>
> Look for the names 'Apache Service' or 'MySQL' in the Source column which have a error symbol in the first column.

The error messages in here are normally very descriptive and will normally lead you to a speciic line number in the `my.ini` file where the error exists. Alternatively, they will idedntify what the issue is.

**Reply to additional info**

Your MySQL error log is basically saying that it cannot start MYSQL as something is already listening on port 3306 (3306 is the default MYSQL port). Almost definitely the MySQL Server that you installed with the Workbench.

I see the installer for "MYSQL Workbench" has changed since I installed "MYSQL Workbench". I expect you chose to install MYSQL Workbench and a MySQL Server. As you have MYSQL Server installed with WAMPServer, can I suggest that you uninstall "MYSQL Workbench" or at least the "MYSQL Server" that came with workbench. This should stop the other MYSQL Server from getting port 3306 before the MYSQL Server installed with WAMPServer.

Remember to backup any databases that you may have created before uninstalling.

You can then install "MYSQL Workbench" again after WAMPServer starts working and this time dont install another instance of MYSQL Server.

Comment: thanks for the neat explanation again. As it was hard to understand and resolve the issue, i have updated my question with the specification provided. Please check the same

Comment: See my additional info.

Answer (score 3):

after you installed vcredist_x64/86.exe ,
you need to reinstall the wampserver. because the instalation of mysql services are not completed without vcredist_x64/86.exe and runtime

Comment: This is the one! Thank you